# Argument of type '(state: State, action: AuthActionsUnion) => State' is not assignable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8

I keep getting the following error in my **main.module.ts**. This is the code below:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PressComponent,
    LegalComponent,
    InviteComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  imports: [
    HomeModule,
    MainRoutingModule,
    ContactModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot([
      AuthEffects
    ]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(AuthReducer, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
    SectionHeaderGroupModule,
    FormRegisterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})

export class MainModule {
}
```

This is error:

```
Error:(34, 25) TS2345: Argument of type '(state: State, action: AuthActionsUnion) => State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionReducerMap<State, Action> | InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<State, Action>>'.
  Type '(state: State, action: AuthActionsUnion) => State' is not assignable to type 'InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<State, Action>>'.
    Property '_desc' is missing in type '(state: State, action: AuthActionsUnion) => State'.
```

This is my **auth.reducer.ts** file:

```
import { IUser } from '../shared/models/user';
import * as AuthActions from './auth.actions';

export interface State {
  user: IUser | null;
  error: any;
}

const initialState: State = {
  user: null,
  error: '',
};

export function AuthReducer(state = initialState, action: AuthActions.AuthActionsUnion): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.GetUserDataGoogleSignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.SignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.SignUp: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.GoogleSignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.MobileGoogleSignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.FacebookSignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.MobileFacebookSignIn: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.SignInFailure: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        error: getErrorMessage(action.payload),
      };
    }
    case AuthActions.AuthActionsTypes.SignUpFailure: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        error: getErrorMessage(action.payload),
      };
    }
  }
}

function getErrorMessage(error): string {
  switch (error) {
    case 'auth/wrong-password':
      return 'Wrong password';
    case 'auth/user-not-found':
      return 'IUser does not exist';
    case 'auth/invalid-email':
      return 'Invalid email address';
    default:
      return error;
  }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The first parameter of StoreModule.forRoot method must be reducer and second parameter must be 'config'.Make sure your AuthReducer is of type reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you mix up between syntax of ngrx v8 and v7 here is how I config my code

In app.module.ts

```
StoreModule.forRoot(ROOT_REDUCERS, {
  metaReducers,
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true
  }
}),
```

Then root reducer

```
import {
  ActionReducer,
  ActionReducerMap,
  MetaReducer,
  Action
} from "@ngrx/store";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import * as fromRouter from "@ngrx/router-store";
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * Every reducer module's default export is the reducer function itself. In
 * addition, each module should export a type or interface that describes
 * the state of the reducer plus any selector functions. The `* as`
 * notation packages up all of the exports into a single object.
 */
/**
 * As mentioned, we treat each reducer like a table in a database. This means
 * our top level state interface is just a map of keys to inner state types.
 */
export interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<any>;
}

/**
 * Our state is composed of a map of action reducer functions.
 * These reducer functions are called with each dispatched action
 * and the current or initial state and return a new immutable state.
 */
export const ROOT_REDUCERS = new InjectionToken<
  ActionReducerMap<State, Action>
>("Root reducers token", {
  factory: () => ({
    router: fromRouter.routerReducer
  })
});
```

And how ngrx v8 write reducer

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import {
  EntityState,
  EntityAdapter,
  createEntityAdapter
} from "@ngrx/entity";

import * as PostActions from "../actions/post.actions";

import { IPost } from "../models/post.model";

export interface PostState extends EntityState<IPost> {
  selectedPost: IPost;
  errors: any;
}

const postAdapter: EntityAdapter<IPost> = createEntityAdapter<IPost>();

const initialState: PostState = postAdapter.getInitialState({
  selectedPost: null,
  errors: null
});

export const postReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PostActions.LoadPostsSuccess, (state, { posts }) =>
    postAdapter.addAll(posts, state)
  ),
  on(PostActions.LoadPostSuccess, (state, { post }) => {
    return postAdapter.addOne(post, { ...state, selectedPost: post });
  }),
  on(PostActions.UpdatePost, (state, { post }) => {
    return postAdapter.updateOne(post, state);
    //return postAdapter.updateOne(post, { ...state, selectedPost: post });
  }),
  on(PostActions.UpdateSelectedPost, (state, { selectedPost }) => {
    console.log(selectedPost);
    return { ...state, selectedPost };
  }),

  //catch errors
  on(
    PostActions.LoadPostsFail,
    PostActions.LoadPostFail,
    PostActions.UpdatePostFail,
    (state, { errors }) => {
      return { ...state, errors };
    }
  )
);

export const { selectAll } = postAdapter.getSelectors();
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. I am getting this error now: `Type '{ router: <T extends BaseRouterStoreState = SerializedRouterStateSnapshot>(state: RouterReducerState<T>, acti
on: Action) => RouterReducerState<T>; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducerMap<State, Action>'.
  Property 'user' is missing in type '{ router: <T extends BaseRouterStoreState = SerializedRouterStateSnapshot>(state: RouterReducerState<T>, action: Action) => RouterReduc
erState<T>; }'.`

Comment: Where do you have that error. Can you take a screen shot and update full code to your question